# What is the due process for the appeal of moderator actions on the stack exchange network?

Tags: feature-request, account-suspension

In the U.S. at least, due process is considered a right that is so important that it is guaranteed by the Bill of Rights.

> Due process balances the power of law of the land and protects the individual person from it. When a government harms a person without following the exact course of the law, this constitutes a due process violation, which offends the rule of law.

-Wikipedia

It is important that the Stack Exchange network ensure that there is a due process for appealing all moderator actions on every Stack Exchange site.
The federal powers of the SEN reign supreme over the individuals statehoods of the individual SE sites. The SEN must enable due process to appeal the unfair timed bans on individual SE sites because an appeal is not possible when a person is banned. There is no way for a banned user to post a meta question or to request an appeal in any way on the site that banned him.

Due Process is not something limited to huge governments, nations, or courtrooms. It is what is simply the standardization of a system of conflict resolution. This standardization helps to prevent abuse by individuals entrusted with authority.

You have heard the saying 'power corrupts--absolute power corrupts absolutely.'
People who enjoy abusing other people tend to seek out positions of authority. No, we cannot legislate morality, but in the immortal words of Martin Luther King, “Morality cannot be legislated, but behavior can be regulated. Judicial decrees may not change the heart, but they can restrain the heartless.”

> The utility of internal organizational systems of conflict resolution, or “due process,” rests on the formulation of specific objectives and values, a high degree of decision-maker independence, balanced formality of procedures, and matching types of conflict with means of resolution.

Please incorporate this new feature. Do it for MLK. Do it for the dream.

Comment: Couldn't you just appeal a per-site ban by asking about it here? Like you just did?

Comment: Just use the "contact us" link in the footer, that's the appeal process

Comment: Maybe a better approach is to prevent you get banned so you keep the option to interact with the community and its moderators.

Comment: It is important to remember that the Stack Exchange network is not a country, nor are individual sites states, nor are individual users citizens. The Federal/State/Citizen **analogy** is quite useful at times, but stretched too far it becomes ridiculous.

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way, but [you can't simply cite laws everywhere on the Internet](http://xkcd.com/1357/).

Comment: @Shog9 The Stack Exchange secessionist movement! Sovereign data centers! Death penalty for spam!

Comment: Also (I add, having researched this a bit)... If you find yourself making the writings of gruff old engineers look like the cooings of preschool teachers in comparison to your own, you should probably stop and have a long, long think about the direction your life is headed in before you write another word.

Comment: @user322404 Shog9's email is in his profile.

Comment: There's a moderator still waiting for a reply from you; I wouldn't want to get in the way of that. I strongly recommend you put more thought and perhaps self-reflection into your next reply than you did into your previous; you have 30 days, take your time and make it count.

Comment: Step 1: Learn to take criticism.  Step 2: Follow the policies inherent in SE, especially the one about being nice.  Step 3: **Don't** automatically assume you're right, especially when you're a relative newcomer to a group.  Follow those rules, and you'll get a pretty decent reception.  Arguing with established users won't.

Comment: The only people above the moderators' heads are those at SE, so that's the only way to appeal. As mentioned, there are contact links. What are you wanting people to say about the broader issue? A vague post about the importance of due process seems unlikely to start any real discussion about it. If you have suggestions about making that process clearer or better, maybe that would be a better starting point?

Comment: @user322404 serious question - do you have a convincing argument to influence our thoughts on this proposal?  I read your post, it is not convincing at all.

Comment: Frankly, trying to be funny and saying, "Do it for MLK. Do it for the dream." (and quoting him) isn't clever. It's more than a little bit rude, and, quite frankly, comparing your actions to those of Dr. King is probably deserving of a suspension.

Comment: @HDE226868 you calling it a joke is what is rude. I'm very serious. Due process helps ensure people get equal treatment. If that's not part of the dream, what do you think the dream is?

Comment: I'll say this and then stop: Comparing a time when you were annoyed with another person on the Internet to a time when people were non-violently fighting for the right to live in peace with others is *not* an apt comparison.

Comment: @HDE226868 You should never have started. This post is about improving SEN to make it fair to everyone.

Comment: It's the same everywhere, you want respect for you *and* for your ideas - you have to earn it.

Comment: @santiago Careful - everyone here is entitled to respect, and so are their posts. That doesn't mean they can't be told they're wrong, but the last thing we need is to endorse or encourage disrespect.

Comment: I am not 'endorsing ot encouraging disresepect' - I am saying that, it is a fact that respect is earned.  I start from a neutral perspective and go from there.

Answer (score 28):

This feature exists. You post on the meta of the site on which you have a problem. If the problem is network wide, you post here. You include enough details for everyone to grasp the issue, and you hang around and respond to comments and answers. It works remarkably well.

Sometimes users come to understand why a moderator action was taken. Sometimes a moderator action is reversed. Sometimes something else happens, but generally all participants leave both happier and wiser.

Since you have been suspended on Electronics for rule violations, I presume you got a message from a moderator telling you about the suspension. If you believe you didn't break any rules and should be unsuspended, Electronics Meta is the best place to raise that issue. If that's impossible, you might get an explanation here. Think of it less as an appeal to a court (this isn't a country or a government) and more of a request for understanding about what you did and what you should not do again.

Since the comment thread is now a giant mess (I honestly thought there was a bug in the comment notifier due to the numbers it was reporting every few minutes) let me provide some advice about how to take an appeal to meta.

First, you do not have to respond to every comment. **Even if it is wrong.**  If you think someone is lying, or taunting you, or is someone else in disguise, it is possible for you to think that but not share the thought with others. You answering each comment with a rebuttal doesn't actually cause other people to dismiss the first comment or take up your cause as someone who's being picked on. It is more likely to make people think you are misinterpreting what you are being told.

Second, to stay focused on the broader issue (what can I do if a moderator is being rude to me, and then suspends me for saying he's being rude to me) you yourself should stay focused on that issue. Don't tell people they're lying, or bullying, or whatever. Restrict your interactions to those about your specific topic -- moderator behaviour, and the difficulty of appealing a suspension when your suspended-rep prevents you posting on a per site meta. When you wander from that into calling people trolls, corrupt, bullies, puppets and so on, you are not sticking to your actual topic. I really recommend that you do because I think that could be a good thing.

Comment: @RobertLongson the [meta user](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/users/77573/user322404) is probably a more interesting link and the drama surrounding the activity there.

Comment: Such a detailed patient answer from a moderator trying to explain site mores and norms, and why things went south, and it's just dismissed with "this answer is offensive." Some people are very hard to help.

Comment: You can't ask to be unsuspended on a per site meta as you won't have the 5 rep required to post there. That's probably a good thing given his previous meta posts though as the chances that he'd make things worse by doing that seem rather high.

Comment: I am speaking to the broader issue. When things aren't going well, you go to meta, and if you're lucky, people explain it to you. That's my answer and as you can see may meta people think it's right. But I am stumbling at the next part, which is that **you learn from the answers you get on the meta**. Whether per site or here. Now you've escalated from calling those who interact with you  "trolling" (being mean for the cruel fun of it) to "corrupt" (deliberately doing the wrong thing for personal gain). You don't give me the impression of being here to learn or understand at all.

Comment: @user322404 There *are* ways to discuss mod actions. You can post on the site meta, or on MSE if it's a multi-site issue. You can find a mod in chat and ask them, if they're available to talk about it. For an appeal to higher authority, you can email the community team  (one of whom also saw this question, reviewed the suspension, and seems to have agreed with it. Just because it didn't get *your* suspension reversed, doesn't mean they aren't willing to listen to complaints. "Due process" doesn't mean "I win every argument."

Comment: @RobertLongson Fortunately, users don't generally get suspended without being warned first, so they have ample opportunity to discuss on meta at that point if they wish to. (If someone does go straight to suspension, it's because they did something incredibly obviously bad.)

Comment: @cpast You weren't always suspended - you could presumably have posted on your site meta at some point in the past when you began having trouble. And beyond that, cpast mentioned appeal methods (talk directly to moderator, contact community team) which aren't blocked by suspension. His whole comment appears to be reasonable; accusing him of taunting, baiting, or lying (?) is uncalled for, and is the kind of thing that could prompt people to flag your comments as rude, leading to moderator intervention...

Comment: @user322404 You may notice that I (like cpast) mentioned appealing to the community team. If a moderator is truly taunting, bullying, and antagonizing, include examples of it in your appeal. I don't want there to be bad mods out there any more than you do. However, please forgive me if I am somewhat skeptical of your claims; in this very discussion you've accused someone of taunting you when he made a reasonable comment, and I have seen similar things happen more times than I can remember.

Comment: @user322404 And there goes every single bit of credibility you had left.  Good bye.

Comment: @user322404 I think I was pretty specific: someone said something reasonable to you, and you responded with hostile accusations. If you want people to stop making this about you, then you might consider being more courteous to others; as it is, it's very easy for people to see why you might have gotten suspended, and why due process isn't going to help you. (I also left a comment on the question half an hour ago about a better way to ask about this kind of thing.)

Comment: @user322404 Who said anything about kissing boots?  What you *do* have to do, though, is **be nice**.  Which you very clearly are not, not with your personal attacks (and for some, rather offensive comments).  Until you are actually receptive to criticism, and you don't attack those trying to help, you will continue to receive a very rough reception.

Comment: @user322404 You're trying to join a community.  A community with norms, standards, and rules.  There is no hubris here, just a re-iteration of the requirements to actually *be* a member here.  If you want to continue to with your personal attacks, you are free to do so.  And we are free to flag, and, eventually, see you suspended here, too.  As for the broader issue, **you've already been told what it is**.  You refusing to accept it doesn't change the fact that you know what it is.

Comment: @user322404 Okay, I've already said all this, but I'll spell it out. cpast made a reasonable comment (there's only one, I think you can see which it is?) and you responded with hostility (accusing him of taunting, etc). And now that you've been called on your hostility a few times, you're escalating even further. This is *exactly* the kind of thing the Be Nice policy is meant to stop, and so it's the kind of thing that people get suspended for. If you want to have a conversation about due process without people talking about you personally, be nice.

Comment: @user322404 I said nothing about you making personal attacks against *me*.  Just that you were making personal attacks, which is very self evident in these comments alone.  As for me being a puppet account, well, hate to disappoint, but I've been around for...quite a while.  Almost three years, in fact.  I don't know who Alexeev is, but I'm very sure that I am not him.

Comment: @user322404 Being defensive is one thing.  Being hostile and *attacking* those criticizing your posts is something very different.  You are displaying the latter.  I'd recommend taking a deep breath, and walking away.  You're too close to this.  Come back when you're calmer.  You were doing well here, and then you started misinterpreting moderator actions as bullying and taunting.  And, I re-iterate, I'm not a puppet account.  You not believing me is irrelevant.

Comment: What I am seeing here from @user322404 is "Waaaaah! I did not get my own way" tantrum, with all the associated strawmen, ad hominems, personal attacks... failing to realise that these tactics will not work - SE will stay the same success story.

Comment: `why don't you post constructively` - yes, why don't you?  (you are projecting)

Comment: @user322404 Do I?  Would you happen to have a link to his profile?  I'd really like to meet this person who is so similiar to me.

Comment: @user322404 No one here is trying to bait you. People are saying "You are not being nice, please stop". Once you do, we can go back to our regular programming.

Comment: @user322404 You can't have an exemption from the Be Nice policy. Asking people to not make it about you doesn't change that. If you want to have a discussion about appeal of moderator actions, *post a more specific question about it*, and don't be rude to people in the ensuing discussion.

Comment: no, you haven't - far from it and i have better things to do than feeding an obvious troll

Comment: @user322404 we haven't met, so you don't know this, but now you do. I never lie. I would certainly not start now to win an argument on the Internet. Your constant focus on the motivations of the people who are trying to help you by explaining the site norms is keeping you from learning the things they're (we're) trying to teach you. Try just accepting statements about moderation, on/off topic, and site norms (but not about you or any person in this thread) as true, and see what changes in your world if those things are true. Try it.

Comment: "What you should not do again" might be nothing. But I doubt it. Like many people before me, I'm out. I hope this feels like some sort of win to you so that you have some return on all this desperate typing and name calling.

Comment: @user322404 Please don't use suggested edits to try to change someone else's opinion.

Comment: On a different note - @KateGregory you are close to a Reversal!  Very nicely put and pertinent answer!

Comment: @Santiago I have 14 Reversals - on Meta they are far easier than on any other site. Every one of them is a little sad though - someone who just totally doesn't get it and can't be helped though many are trying.

Comment: @KateGregory You're right, I don't get it. Why is it okay and supported for anyone to personally attack me, but it is wrong when I defend myself and assert myself as an equal? Why is general principle of the post ignored in favor of judging the individual who posted it? What is up with that?

Comment: I'm supposed to be out, but I will try once. I did not attack you, @user322404. I have tried to explain the norms of the site. I have objected to you calling other people names, telling me I'm judging you, or telling me I'm lying. It is not an attack to say "I am not lying". You are not defending yourself or asserting yourself as an equal, you are telling everyone about other people's motivation (btw, you appear to be wrong) and saying very little about yourself other than that you feel attacked, which you phrase as being attacked. Since you can't trust me, you can't learn from me. Shame..

Comment: @KateGregory See, you defend yourself when you perceive you have been accused of something. I in fact was using the generic 'you' and I edited it when I noticed it might be taken personally. But why is it okay for you to stand up for yourself but wrong for me to do the same? How can I trust a hypocrite?

Comment: This is going nowhere; I'm sticking a fork in it. Thanks for trying to help, Kate.

Comment: Shog, I wrote this answer http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/48054/102 on workplace just now, and reading the third paragraph after submitting it, a lightbulb went off. For me and for @user322404. Sigh.